# Flutter video_editor: ^3.0.0 cutting video framing

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently utilizing the video_editor: ^3.0.0 plugin to trim videos when selecting them from the Gallery. While previewing the video in the CropGridViewer's constructor, I've noticed that the video frame gets cropped from the edges vertically. However, when I utilize CropGridViewer.edit, the video frame adjusts perfectly. I've included a screenshot and the relevant code below for your reference. I appreciate your assistance in understanding this issue better.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl/ffmpeg_kit.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl/log.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl/return_code.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl/statistics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:media_scanner/media_scanner.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_editor/video_editor.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:videocutter/Tab/TabBarViewWidget.dart';
import 'package:videocutter/Trim/video_trim.dart';



class Trim extends StatefulWidget {
  const Trim({Key? key, required this.file}) : super(key: key);

  final File file;

  @override
  State<Trim> createState() => _TrimState();
}

class _TrimState extends State<Trim> {
  late final VideoEditorController _controller;
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  int duration = 0;


  String formatter(Duration duration) =>
      [
        duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0'),
        duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')
      ].join(":");

  final double height = 60;
  ValueNotifier<int> progressNotifier = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController =
    VideoPlayerController.file(widget.file)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          duration = _videoPlayerController.value.duration.inSeconds;
        });
      });

    _controller = VideoEditorController.file(
      File(widget.file.path),
      minDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      maxDuration: Duration(
          seconds: 60), // Default value, can be updated later
    );

    _controller.initialize(aspectRatio: 16 / 9).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        // Update maxDuration after _controller has been initialized
        _controller.maxDuration =
            Duration(seconds: duration > 0 ? duration : 60);
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      // handle minimum duration bigger than video duration error
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// Basic export video function
  /// Basic export video function


  bool istrim = true;
  int progress = 0;
  String? fileName;



  Future<void> trimVideos() async {

    try {

      Directory mainFolder = Directory('${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/trim/cut/');
      final String outputPath= '${mainFolder.path}/$fileName.mp4';

      //final String outputPath = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/trim/cut/$fileName.mp4';
      final String inputPath = widget.file.path;

      final Duration start = _controller.startTrim;
      final Duration end = _controller.endTrim;

      final command =
          '-ss ${formatter(start)} -t ${formatter(end - start)} -noaccurate_seek -i "$inputPath" -codec copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 "$outputPath"';

      int totalVideoDuration = (end - start).inMilliseconds;
      int totalProgress = 0;

      // Execute FFmpeg command
      await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command, (session) async {
        final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

        print('The command is executed: $command');

        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
           print('working fine $returnCode');
           progressNotifier.value = 100;
           Navigator.pushReplacement(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabBarViewWidget(initialIndex: 0, showAppBar: true)),
           );
        }

      }, (Log log) {
        // Log callback
      }, (Statistics statistics) {
        if (statistics == null) {
          return;
        }
        if (statistics.getTime() > 0) {
          // Calculate the percentage of completion
          totalProgress = (statistics.getTime() * 100) ~/ totalVideoDuration;
          progress = totalProgress;
          print('Progress: $progress%');

          progressNotifier.value=progress;


        }

      });
      // MediaScanner.loadMedia(path: outputPath);
      print('Execution completed successfully');
      // Navigator.push(
      //   context,
      //   MaterialPageRoute(
      //     builder: (context) => TabBarViewWidget(initialIndex: 1),
      //   ),
      // );




    } catch (e) {
      print('Error trimming video: $e');
    }
  }







  Future _showFileNameDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    TextEditingController fileNameController = TextEditingController();

    return showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter  Name'),
          content: TextField(
            controller: fileNameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: '${DateFormat('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').format(DateTime.now())}'),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(context, fileNameController.text.trim());
                if(fileNameController.text==null||fileNameController.text.isEmpty){
                  fileName= DateFormat('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').format(DateTime.now());
                  print('The file name is $fileName');
                }else{
                  fileName=fileNameController.text.trim();
                  print('The file name is $fileName');
                }
              trimVideos();
              },
              child: Text('OK'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, null); // Cancel
              },
              child: Text('Cancel'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),

            )
          ],
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Trim video'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _controller.initialize(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return _buildTrimWidget();
            } else {
              return Center(child:
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),

                ],

              ));
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }


    Widget _buildTrimWidget() {
      if (_controller.initialized) {
        return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // Adjust height as desired
                  child: CropGridViewer.preview(
                    controller: _controller,

                  ),
                ),
                AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _controller.video,
                  builder: (_, __) =>
                      AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: _controller.isPlaying ? 0 : 1,
                        duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: _controller.video.play,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.play_arrow,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                _showFileNameDialog(context);
              },
              child: Text('Trim Now')
          ),
          ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
              valueListenable: progressNotifier,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return value < 100
                    ? Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('Progress: $value%'),
                    LinearProgressIndicator(
                      value: value / 100,
                      minHeight: 10,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
                    : Container(); // Empty container when progress is finished
              }),

          ..._trimSlider(),
        ],
      );
      } else {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    }

    List<Widget> _trimSlider() {
      return [
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: Listenable.merge([
            _controller,
            _controller.video,
          ]),
          builder: (_, __) {
            final int duration = _controller.videoDuration.inSeconds;
            final double pos = _controller.trimPosition * duration;

            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: height / 4),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text('${formatter(Duration(seconds: pos.toInt()))}'),
                  const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                  AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: _controller.isTrimming ? 1 : 0,
                    duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text(formatter(_controller.startTrim)),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text(formatter(_controller.endTrim)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: height / 4),
          child: TrimSlider(
            controller: _controller,
            height: height,
            horizontalMargin: height / 4,
            child: TrimTimeline(
              controller: _controller,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ];
    }
  }
```

[image: using CropGridViewer.preview constructor]

[image: using CropGridViewer.edit]